# Как быстро вставить данные из списка в таблицу MS SQL? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Суть вопроса: Есть огромная база данных (300.000 строк, 90 столбцов). С помощью CsvHelper преобразовываю её в список. Как быстро(!!!) выставить данные из списка в таблицу базы данных MS SQL? Пробовал с помощью SetRange, вылетает с NullReferenceException, а через foreach - слишком долго...

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: SqlBulkCopy class почитайте

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Можно использовать SqlBulkCopy. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8